# Adding a file to a target for specific build configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I have 2 files which I want to include into my target selectively based on my build configuration. For instance, when I am building on PROD build configuration then file 1 should get added to the target otherwise file 2 should get added to the target.

How do we achieve this build setting in XCODE 4.2?

Comment: You can add another one target with file 2

Comment: I do not want to create a separate target just for this reason. Is there any way to add file in the same target based on the kind of build it is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a file for a specific configuration. But what you can do is to `#if` your entire file and set the macro accordingly for each configuration in the target build settings:

```c
#if MY_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG

/* your code here */

#endif
```

Comment: How does the second option works. Can you please elaborate? Additionally, My file is not a .m or .h file. Its a .mobileprovision file.